# Question about Cloudfront access API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

My frontend code is deployed in Cloudfront and tries to access Lambda through API Gateway. However, the API Gateway is authenticated with AWS_IAM which means it seems that frontend cannot access it directly. So I wonder if there are any methods I can access API Gateway like for example use Cognito to act as an authorizer or something else?

Answer (score 0):

- I have used the [this aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-2/), which show how to use API keys between an Amazon CloudFront distribution and API Gateway to secure access to your API in API Gateway in addition to your preferred authorization (AuthZ) mechanism already set up in API Gateway.